# Cancel button showDialogInput issues

Tags: java, button, nullpointerexception

```
 NumberFormat numForm = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    double itemPrice;
    String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter item price:");
    if (s.equals("") || s == null) {


    } else {
        try{

            itemPrice = Double.parseDouble (s);
            recordPurchase(itemPrice);
            txtPrice.setText(numForm.format(itemPrice));

            double subtotal = getPurchase();     

            txtSubtotal.setText(numForm.format(subtotal));
            int items = getItems();
            String totalItems = Integer.toString(items);
            txtItems.setText(totalItems);

        } // end try
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You must enter positive numeric data!");
        } // end catch
    } // end if Else
```

I am currently working on a program.My issue is in the if statement where I check to see if the user hits okay with nothing in the box OR they select cancel. I get a NullPointerException error only when cancel is clicked. If anyone could clarify as to why this happens it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when the user clicks cancel, the return value is null. I see you tried to fix this by adding the test `s == null`, but that is in the wrong place. Your if statement should be:

```
if (s == null || s.equals("")) {
```